# Tick labels on x-axis aren't symmetric (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot hysteresis loops that all have a (nominally) symmetric range of x-values (2 -> 0 -> -2 -> 0 -> 2, for example).

However, due to slight variation in the magnet power supply sometimes the start and end values aren't exactly +/- 2, but might be -2.01.  This means that the plots that I produce do not have a symmetric x-axis.  It might go from -2.5 to 2.

Is there a way to force the axis to be symmetric around 0?  I've tried `matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator(symmetric=True)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import os, re, glob, io

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator(symmetric=True)

upsrt = pd.DataFrame({'DAC3' : pd.Series([-2.1, -1., 0., 1., 2.]),
                      'norm' : pd.Series([5., 3., 6., 8., 2.])})

downsrt = pd.DataFrame({'DAC3' : pd.Series([-2., -1., 0., 1., 2.]),
                        'norm' : pd.Series([3., 7., 3., 6., 7.])})

upsrt.plot(x='DAC3', y='norm', color='red', label='Up')

downsrt.plot(x='DAC3', y='norm', color='blue', label='Down')

plt.show()
```

Note that the two DAC3 series differ, lowest values are -2 and -2.1 which is what's causing the problem.

Also, I can't force the axis to go from -2.5 to 2 because I'm plotting lots of figures in a loop and each has a different range.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the locator for the specific `axes` object, and then supply those `axes` as argument to `DataFrame.plot()`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(symmetric=True))

upsrt = pd.DataFrame({'DAC3' : pd.Series([-2.1, -1., 0., 1., 2.]),
                      'norm' : pd.Series([5., 3., 6., 8., 2.])})

downsrt = pd.DataFrame({'DAC3' : pd.Series([-2., -1., 0., 1., 2.]),
                        'norm' : pd.Series([3., 7., 3., 6., 7.])})

upsrt.plot(x='DAC3', y='norm', color='red', label='Up',ax=axes)

downsrt.plot(x='DAC3', y='norm', color='blue', label='Down', ax=axes)

plt.show()
```